# NSS Apache SSL Incorrect Password

Tags: apache, ssl, nss

I'm setting up NSS for my Apache server but I'm running into an error. I feel like this is a really easy fix that I'm overlooking.

Here's my Apache error log:

```
[Tue Mar 21 16:09:13 2017] [error] Password for slot internal is incorrect.
[Tue Mar 21 16:09:13 2017] [error] NSS initialization failed. Certificate database: /etc/apache2/nssdb/.
[Tue Mar 21 16:09:13 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: -8177 The security password entered is incorrect
[Tue Mar 21 16:14:22 2017] [error] Password for slot internal is incorrect.
[Tue Mar 21 16:14:22 2017] [error] NSS initialization failed. Certificate database: /etc/apache2/nssdb/.
[Tue Mar 21 16:14:22 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: -8177 The security password entered is incorrect
[Tue Mar 21 16:24:25 2017] [error] Password for slot internal is incorrect.
[Tue Mar 21 16:24:25 2017] [error] NSS initialization failed. Certificate database: /etc/apache2/nssdb/.
[Tue Mar 21 16:24:25 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: -8177 The security password entered is incorrect
[Tue Mar 21 16:29:00 2017] [error] Password for slot internal is incorrect.
[Tue Mar 21 16:29:00 2017] [error] NSS initialization failed. Certificate database: /etc/apache2/nssdb/.
[Tue Mar 21 16:29:00 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: -8177 The security password entered is incorrect
```

I checked `apachectl -t`, here is the output:

```
[Tue Mar 21 17:16:23 2017] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Mar 21 17:16:23 2017] [warn] module proxy_http_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Mar 21 17:16:23 2017] [warn] module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Mar 21 17:16:23 2017] [warn] module proxy_http_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/NSSPin.conf:
Invalid command 'token:password', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Here is my nss.conf file:

```
NSSPassPhraseDialog file:/etc/apache2/conf.d/NSSPin.txt
NSSPassPhraseHelper /usr/sbin/nss_pcache
```

I've tried multiple combinations of `NSSPassPhraseDialog` with file, exec, "password", password. In my /etc/apache2/conf.d/NSSPin.txt file (the file that `NSSPassPhraseDialog` is being linked to) I've tried "password", password, toke:password, token:"password", internal:password, internal:"password". I'm not really sure what else to do.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww How is this not relevant to programming? That's ridiculous...

Comment: The best I can tell, you are having a web server configuration issue. A good sniff test is, can you show your code. I'm guessing the answer is NO because its just a configuration issue. There are more appropriate sites for questions about configuring web servers.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, when I figure out the answer, I'll still post it on here just in case someone else runs across this issue.